# How to define route name for nested resource in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, routes

I've got nested resources in my ember routes. Lets suppose according [this example](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources), that my `router.js` looks like:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' }, function() {
    this.resource('comment', { path ':comment_id' });
  });
});
```

The documentation says this should generate routes like:

```
/post/:post_id              post.index
/post/:post_id/:comment_id  comment.index
```

However I would like these to be `post.show` and `comment.show`, how do I rename these routes?

Comment: I have answered your question. My example works for your?

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior This is rather a workaround for me than a solution. However in your JSbin example the comments are not listed, and I can't confirm its a working.

Comment: Yes it's like a workaround, but I don't find other way. And you can access the comments by http://jsbin.com/ucanam/647#/post/1/1. Or clicking in Marcio link here http://jsbin.com/ucanam/647#/post/1

Answer (score 1):

I have get this working with the following setup.

Routers with dynamic segment:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('post.show', { path: '/post/:post_id' });
    this.resource('comment.show', { path: '/post/:post_id/:comment_id' });
});
```

Overriding the `serialize` hook of `App.CommentShowRoute` to reflect the url expected:

```
App.CommentShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    serialize: function(model) {       
        return {           
            post_id : model.get("post_id"),
            comment_id : model.get("id")
        };
    }
});
```

The major problem implementating this is the url generated, since the model in the `serialize` hook, isn't loaded, the `post_id` property isn't present, and after the model is loaded this isn't automatically updated. So a `linkTo` targeting a comment will have a url `post/undefined/1`, instead of `post/1/1`. 
Clicking in the link works, because after some time the model is loaded, but if the user refresh the page, will not work, because of the wrong url.

To fix it, I used the 3 approach from [this](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/undefined-properties-in-route-serialize/1213/9) discussion forum comment, where we use the `action` helper instead of `linkTo`. The only diference is that the link will not have the  href` property with the url, but when clicking all works.

The result is that:

```
App.PostShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    events : {
        goToComment: function(context){
            this.transitionTo('comment.show', context);
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/647/edit) with the full implementation.